# x = await GetBla() vs task = GetBla() and then x = await task

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Sorry for bad title, but I think its easier to show an example

This code will run in serial

```
var myFirstItems = await GetMyFirstItems();
var  mySecondItems = await GetMySecondItems();
```

But this code the Get-Methods will run in parallel.

```
var myFirstItemTask = GetMyFirstItems();
var mySecondItemTask = GetMySecondItems();
var myFirstItems = await myFirstItemTask;
var mySecondItems = await mySecondItemTask;
```

Can anyone explain to me why?
In my (apparently) uninformed mind, the two would be equivalent

([Gist](https://sharplab.io/#gist:fc47602230185c4243324a3a368f7153))

Comment: In the second case you kick off the first method and you are not awaiting it to finish rather you kick off the second method. When the execution engine reaches the first `await` inside the `GetMyFirstItems` which is not completed yet then it returns the execution to the caller. That's why you can call the `GetMySecondItems` while the `GetMyFirstItems` awaits for the async Task.

Comment: `await` neither knows nor cares *how* a task is created, what started it running and when or how it will be marked as complete. All it cares about is waiting for that task to finish. In this instance, the job of creating those running tasks is entirely an implementation detail of the `GetMyFirstItems` and `GetMySecondItems` methods.

Comment: One more spin on it that perhaps isn't initially obvious: `GetMyFirstItems()` is what starts the task, not `await`.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the help. Thanks to you and this over-commented Gist https://sharplab.io/#gist:551aa88feb3b3f53513494ea7b9abef6
I now realize that in my 2nd example, but tasks are started in //, and "main execution" is waiting on first await although both tasks are running. If second task is then finished on the second await it immediately returns (of not there will be a bit more waiting on that line as well)